# Master not found after building nopcommerce plugin

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nopcommerce, webshop

I have builded this payment plugin for Nopcommerce 3.70

https://github.com/ePay/nopcommerce

to make it available for Nopcommerce v. 3.70. Building and installation was successful but when I try to configure the module inside nopcommerce I get this error:

> The view 'Nop.Plugin.Payments.ePay.Views.PaymentePay.Configure' or its
>   master was not found or no view engine supports the searched
>   locations. The following locations were searched:
>
> ~/Themes/PowerHub/Views/PaymentePay/Nop.Plugin.Payments.ePay.Views.PaymentePay.Configure.cshtml
>   ~/Themes/PowerHub/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Payments.ePay.Views.PaymentePay.Configure.cshtml
>   ~/Views/PaymentePay/Nop.Plugin.Payments.ePay.Views.PaymentePay.Configure.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Payments.ePay.Views.PaymentePay.Configure.cshtml
>   ~/Administration/Views/PaymentePay/Nop.Plugin.Payments.ePay.Views.PaymentePay.Configure.cshtml
>   ~/Administration/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Payments.ePay.Views.PaymentePay.Configure.cshtml

The only thing I have changed in the source is in the "Description.txt"

> SupportedVersions: 3.60 -> SupportedVersions: 3.70

`Build Action` is set to `Embeded Resource`

Comment: I checked your code. Everything looks correct. Did you try all these clean temp, clean solution, rebuild solution, delete .suo file, restart VS? I mean that it might be not a problem with coding.

Answer (score 1):

For versions 2.00-3.30 the views (.cshtml files) should be marked as an embedded resource. And starting version 3.40, ensure that the "Build Action" property of the view file is set to "Content", and the "Copy to Output Directory" property is set to "Copy if newer".

Comment: This is set, but did not make any change. What can I be missing ?